# Is there a way to verify that an Identifier for Vendor (IDFV) is valid?

Tags: ios, xcode, validation, uniqueidentifier, restful-authentication

Apple has a unique identifier called the Identifier For Vendor (IDFV) discussed in this developers guide. 
http://possiblemobile.com/2013/04/unique-identifiers/

I was thinking to would be possible to use with a Restful API so only requests that have a valid IDFV are accepted. But here is the problem I don't know any way to verify the IDFV. I could make it so when the app is installed it registers with my service. But ideally there would be a way I can verify this identifier.

Comment: It seems like Apple ought to have (in the best of all worlds) a server-side way to determine if a particular IDFV belongs to your app. Is this what you mean? Have you approached Apple about this?

Answer (score 1):

I just had a brain storm on this: It's not all that simple, but what if you have an In-App Purchase for the app where that IAP is on a free tier. Have to investigate this more, but I think you can have a Non-Consumable purchase type that is free. The client can then send the purchase receipt (which is encrypted, as of iOS7) to the server side and the server side can then validate this receipt-- Apple *does* provide a RESTful means of doing this. Thoughts? Of course, you can also make the IAP have some > 0 price. This would give the app developer the means to add a payment mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what your problem is.  The app grabs the identifierForVendor and sends it to your server.  What else can happen?  You could certainly code the transmission so it also sent a hash of the identifierForVendor and some secret string (like "my secret 25671566") to test that the transmission was coming from your app.

You should also know that 1) the identifierForVendor will change if the app is deleted and reinstalled.  2) the keychain might solve the problem of #1 3) The app has a receipt, all apps do whether or not they have purchased an IAP. The receipt is encoded using the identifierForVendor.   You could send the receipt from the device along with the purported identifierForVendor and see if it can be decoded.  But see paragraph 1 above.

Comment: For me, it's a question of how much security do you want. Someone can potentially dig a secret out of your app binary. And then the IFV is just a sequence of characters.